# a strange bug on template's url tag error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm using django 1.4.5.

within my templates, I've included `{% load url from future %}`, and have followed the standard pattern for referring to urls accordingly.

say, in the `urls.py':

```
url(
    regex = r'^$',
    view = MyClassBasedView.as_view(),
    name = 'index'),
```

and inside the template:

```
<a href="{% url "index" %}">back to index</a>
```

But I still get that nasty `syntax error` :

```
**Error during template rendering:**
73 <a href="{% url "index" %}">back to index</a>
```

Do you know why I'm getting this error? Do I miss something ?

Comment: Try single quotes around `index`

Comment: I did .. but it didn't work ..

Comment: Are you sure the error is related to the `url` tag? Looks quite right to me...

Comment: yes .. It should have something to do with the namespaces. I've put all of my apps within the `apps` directory ..

Comment: I restructured the whole project and put the my apps out of `apps` directory ... problem still exists  :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to prefix `index` with your app name, something like: `{% url 'myapp:index' %}`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: that makes sense. I did so, but still get that error. Maybe some namespace collision happened ? I've put all of my apps on `apps` directory and included them on `INSTALLED_APPS`...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any type of quotes to reference a url by name in Django 1.4.x ...

```
{% url index %}
```

... should work. If it doesn't, there may be an error resolving the path.